# Como escrever todas colunas de uma tabela SQL + php

Tags: php, sql, firebird

Boa tarde, estou com uma duvida, eu queria criar um echo que mostrasse todas colunas com um select, meu código está da seguinte forma

```html
<?php
  $db = 'localhost:F:\Dados\TGA.FDB';
  $username = 'SYSDBA';
  $password = 'masterkey';
  // Connect to database
  $dbh = ibase_connect($db, $username, $password);
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM TMOV WHERE IDMOV = 1974';
  // Execute query
  $rc = ibase_query($dbh, $sql);
  // Get the result row by row as object
  while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($rc)) {
    echo $row -> CODCFO, "\n";
    echo $row -> NUMEROMOV, "\n";


  }
  // Release the handle associated with the result of the query
  ibase_free_result($rc);
  // Release the handle associated with the connection
  ibase_close($dbh);
 ?>
```

Então ao invés de usar dois echo tem alguma maneira de eu usar um loop ele repetir todas colunas tipo

```html
for( new colunas; colunas < MAX_COLUNAS; i++){
  echo row[i];
 }
```

eu comecei programar agora em php e ainda não estou habituado com todas sintaxe

Comment: Seria isso? https://teamtreehouse.com/library/combining-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar um [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php):

```html
  while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($rc)) { 
    foreach($row as $coluna) {
     echo $coluna;
    }
  }
```

No caso de você precisar colocar também o nome da coluna seguido do valor, como por exemplo:

```
echo NOMEDACOLUNA1: valordacoluna1
echo NOMEDACOLINA2: valordacoluna2...
```

Também pode utilizar o foreach:

```
while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($rc)) { 
    foreach($row as $nomeColuna => $valorColuna) {
     echo $nomeColuna .": ". $valorColuna; // "NOMECOLUNAx: valorcolunax"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda.